# How to Scale an image, coming from camera, displayed in a framelayout?

Tags: android, android-studio, scaling, aspect-ratio, android-framelayout

i need to scale the image taken from camera and displayed in framelayout (not in imageview) so that it keeps and maintains its aspect ratio.
Till now i have only been able to find image scaling in imageviews, i am unable to do it for framelayout.
Note: i am displaying a picture of sunglasses in imageview on the frame layout, coming from firebase database.
So basically, framelayout is displaying a selfie taken from camera and then i place random sunglasses frames on it which i can drag and rotate on framelayout area.
Code for XML below.

```
 <FrameLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frm"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"

        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, 50, 50, true);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();         
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,stream);
imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromByte(stream.toByteArray(),50,50));
```

But make sure you use it wisely as it might throw

> **java.lang.OutofMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget.**

To avoid this make sure you  check the dimensions of a bitmap before decoding it.

Comment: now this is what i was pointing, you wrote (imageView.setImageBitmap). There's the problem. i am not trying to scale an image in an imageview. i want to scale an image taken from camera and displayed in a framelayout as a background. i want to scale the image to adjust in framelayout as BG so that it doesnt loose its aspect ratio and gets scaled to best possible size.

Comment: @SaAdIrFan  paste your java code of how you are setting the image. i suggest you to use [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) image caching libraries  for better performance.